# How to loop over nested objects in a for loop

Tags: javascript

How can I convert an object like

```
{
  "0": {
    "1": 0,
    "2": 0,
    "3": 0,
  },
  "1": {
    "1": 0,
    "2": 0,
    "3": 0,
  }
}
```

in a loop, so that in every incrementation I have a new object

```
{
 "1": 0,
 "2": 0,
 "3": 0,
}
```

I only managed to produce the last object with

```
var lastObj = obj[ Object.keys(obj).sort().pop()];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to loop over each of the values of your original object, you can just loop over your `Object.values`. This will take each of the values in your object and make an array, which you can then loop over however you like.

```js
let obj = {
    "0": {
      "1": 0,
      "2": 0,
      "3": 0,
    },
    "1": {
      "1": 0,
      "2": 0,
      "3": 0,
    }
  }

Object.values(obj).forEach(o => {
    // do what you want with `o` 
    console.log(o)
})
```

Comment: According to your answer where do you explain this statement: *in a loop, so that in every incrementation **I have a new object***?

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the parent object's keys into an array and then perform the loop:

```
var parentObjectKeys = Object.keys(parentObject);
for (var i = 0; i < parentObjectKeys.length; i++) {
    var childObject = parentObject[parentObjectKeys[i]];
    // Do stuff with childObject;
}
```